# Why does LXDM crash when ever I try to launch "Xubuntu Session" or "XFCE Session"?

Tags: xfce, ubuntu-12.04

When I try to launch anything except *LXDE*, **LXDM** crashes. It takes username & password and returns the same screen asking for username & password.

Why does **LXDM** crash when I try to launch "Xubuntu Session" or "XFCE Session"?

Comment: If you're going to downvote could you at least tell why?

Comment: I wasn't one of the downvoters but prior to you posting an answer your question looks awful... No details at all. No one could possibly answer it but you.

Comment: Which you did.... and now that I think about it the question isn't any better so I'm adding my downvote. Your answer is good so that should balance it out.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You posted 3 questions in succession which are all of poor quality and to all of which you already knew the answer, but still felt like you had to make it sound like an actual question (and, thus, misleading other users).

Comment: .. They were all legitimate questions that I had. None of them were easy to find the answers too, so I asked and self-answered them? What's the problem.

Comment: Xubuntu/Lubuntu gets released in another month. I bet quite a few people find this handy even if you didn't. I ran into the problem in 11.10 and again in 12.04 (and did the work to figure it out again).

Comment: @EvanCarroll: The problem is that your question isn't very detailed.

Comment: No one is going to have a more detailed question. You try to log in and it crashes.. That's all she wrong. No error, no message in logs.

Comment: Arguably if you're playing Jeopardy! here, it's okay if the question itself isn't that detailed, because you know the answer already.

Comment: Exactly, and I still earn exp. So I help others and everyone is happy. And, so long as I ask a lot of questions that I'm going answer at the sametime the downvote-reaper will run and whipe all of my downvotes tonight and then temporarily ban everyone that serial-downvoted me.

Comment: Well, no, that's not going to happen. Also your contributions shouldn't *all* be self-answers. At least not in rapid succession.

Comment: They're not look at my exp log. You're making it sound like my question and answer aren't welcome when per the answer I have **evidence** that I encountered this problem on 2011-11-22 and again on 2012-04-05. I also wrote on the upstream bug report. I'm trying to get the word out and make sure this problem is sufficiently exposed to those looking for the answer. All while earning a few honest EXP points! I feel like I'm not welcome here, and I'm constantly having to shake the haters off. I even tagged this right to help it get indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `LXDM` is bugged in `12.04` and `11.10`. You can find more information on the [bug and the status of the fix on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxdm/+bug/875991). You would have encountered this bug if you use `XFCE` or `xubuntu-desktop` as packaged by Ubuntu and you try to use `LXDM` to launch it. Or, more probably if you installed Lubuntu and then tried to migrated over to Xubuntu. Essentially, `LXDM` can't handle a space in the name and you'll have to edit a configuration file.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxdm/+bug/875991